# STM32_OC_Timing and IRQHandler

Tags: microcontroller, c

I created a program to simple time base delay (in seconds). I have problem:

How to read a interrupt flag from channel 1 etc.?

When I use `if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(&htim2, TIM_FLAG_CC1) != RESET)` an error occurs.

When the interrupt occurred , uC should clear flag and set Blue LED in Discovery Board.

Here is my program:

**Main.c**

```
/* Includes */
#include "stm32f3xx_hal.h"

/* Private variables */
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;

/* Private function prototypes */
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);

int main(void)
{

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
 HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();

  /* Infinite loop */

  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_11,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  }
}

/** System Clock Configuration*/

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2);

  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

}

/* TIM2 init function */
void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 7199; //72Mhz/7200 
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2);

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig);

  HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim2);

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig);

  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TIMING;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 20000; //0.0001[s] * 20000 = 2 [s] DELAY
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TIMING;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 30000;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2);

  HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htim2,TIM_CHANNEL_1 );
  //HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htim2,TIM_CHANNEL_2 );
}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
     PC9   ------> I2S_CKIN
*/
void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PC9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

 /*
  * Configure GPIO pin : PE8 BLUE LED
  */

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin=GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode=GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull=GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed=GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE,&GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin=GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode=GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull=GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed=GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE,&GPIO_InitStruct);

/*
 * COnfigure GPIO pin : PE11 GREEN LED
 */

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin=GPIO_PIN_11;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode=GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull=GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed=GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE,&GPIO_InitStruct);
}
```

low level implementation:

```
void HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim_base)
{
  if(htim_base->Instance==TIM2)
  {
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* Peripheral interrupt init*/
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);

  }

}

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_8,GPIO_PIN_SET);

  // HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_12);
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim2); //THis function is implemented by StmCubeMX , WHAT IS THIS?
}
```

So how should my `TIM2_IRQHandler` look like? Each channel generate delay in +1 sec. When I am debugging this program, when LED is set the period is equal to 1s (time for set LED).

Comment: What is the error that you receive? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Also, could you remove the HTML formatting from your code?

Answer (score 1):

(This really should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment, my apologies)

I'm not very familiar with this "HAL" version of ST's library, but how I normally do timers with STM32 is the following:

```
void TIM2_IRQHandler()
{
     if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM2, TIM_IT_CC1) != RESET)
     {
          TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2, TIM_IT_CC1);

          // TODO: Your code
     }
}
```

Hopefully that translates to your environment.  In terms of your error, you'll need to be more descriptive about what the error is for us to help you.